# C# regular expressions which returns the next line

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regular expression which matches a specific statement and returns the next line.

for instance, from the the following lines, I want to match the "token" and get the "content1" & "content2".

```
some statement
token
content1
some other statement
some othe statement 2
token
content2
continutes
.....
```

I have tried this statement but I think it's fundamentally wrong.

```
var r = new Regex("token.*(\r\n){2}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Please read [ask] and share what you have tried.

Comment: You should augment your question with additional rules explaining how many spaces are expected between the repeated string and the 'line number' e.g. 0-x spaces

Comment: @Robin It's nondeterministic. The only think I can think of, is to discover the end of next line by having \n or \r\n.

Comment: @Mori How do you match the second content? Is it a suffixed number or something else? What links `content1` with `content2`, `content3`, etc?

Comment: @silkfire The requirement is to collect the lines after the lines which contain "token".  There is no other rules. Just the first line after the lines with the value of "token"

Comment: I personally wouldn't use regex here. It seems trivial to iterate through this text line by line, flagging when you see `token` and then pushing the next line into e.g. a collection seems straightforward enough.

Comment: @Mori Then I'd definitely not use regex either. I'd split the text on a newline and would look for the desired line in the resulting array and then just pick the element that comes after. Pretty simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the regex

```
(?<=\ntoken\n).*
```

It uses positive look-behind to find a line consisting of only `token` then matches everything on the next line.

[See this example at ideone](http://ideone.com/nxfRuk).

Comment: Should you really be checking if `token` is preceded by a new line character? I mean, what if it's in the beginning of the string?